# System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'The HTTP request is not authorized with the "Anonymous"

Tags: c#

I've got a C# app that sends data to a web server. many clients work fine.
now I've set up another client with the same config, from this client I receive this:

```
22:58:39 startSync ConnectionLost 
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: Richiesta 
HTTP vietata con lo schema di autenticazione client 'Anonymous'. -- 
-> System.Net.WebException: Errore del server remoto: (403) Non 
consentito. 
in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
--- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---

Server stack trace: 
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory)
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

I've changed only the sim on the router (client side), internet work fine.

I don't know what happens. I think the problem is on the client's side.

edit:

this si the webconfig on the server side:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    
    
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
          <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
          <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        </system.web>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ALSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ALSModel.csdl|res://*/ALSModel.ssdl|res://*/ALSModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=ALS;user id=user;Password=aaaaaa;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="SetupPassword" value="password" />
        <add key="LogFolder" value="Logs" />
        <add key="FederazioneGlobale" value = "da15b962-0170-4dfa-b684-5e7c698a5fea" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ALBasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00"
              sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered" messageEncoding="Text">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                          <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
          <service name="AL.WebServer.ALClients">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ALBasicHttpBinding" contract="AL.WebServer.IALClients" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

the config on the client side is the same then other.

on the iis:

[image]

there is only anonymous

Comment: The community needs more information to help you. Post your HTTP client implementation and explain how the web API is secured.

Comment: You are getting a 403 `forbidden` error code, which means you are _not_ passing the _authorization_ check. Check if you have configured everything properly related to login credentials on the client side.

Comment: Some server do not allow multiple connections from same source IP address.

Comment: You are using Authentication.  Authentication means the same client account must be valid on both client and server.  So the clients and server must share the same password server to validate the account which is how windows authentication works.  So either the client machine is not in the same group as the other clients, or the user account isn't part of the group.

Comment: ok but how can find user and password?